# The TomEE issue on startup

Tags: java, apache-tomee

Right after TomEE startup the issue comes:

```
WARNING: Can't set TomEE ServerEndpointConfig$Configurator
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultImpl
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:2062)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.forceEEServerEndpointConfigurator(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:338)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.<init>(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:284)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatLoader.initialize(TomcatLoader.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.install(ServerListener.java:168)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.ServerListener.lifecycleEvent(ServerListener.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
```

No other consequences, however why it happens? 
I can provide more information, if needed

Comment: may be missed attribute in configuration?

Comment: Rustam, maybe, if you know, how to find out which one attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using TomEE with `javaee-api-7.0.jar` in your TomEE 1.6 / 1.7 lib directory? I started seeing this same message as well once I started trying to use some of the Java EE 7 functionality by replacing the EE6 jar with the EE7 one.

At the time of writing this, TomEE does not support the Java EE 7 spec (which is likely why we are getting that strange error). However, there is a TomEE 2.0 Snapshot which includes a `javaee-api-7.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and the error does not show up in my console while using it.

http://tomee.apache.org/download/tomee-2.0.0-snapshot.html

You can use the whole distribution, or simply grab the EE7 jar.